# Display person's name from face detection

Tags: javascript, html

I've written this face detection code in just js. At the moments inside the labels folder I have faces of individuals and when they come close to the webcam using features of faceapi it matches the webcam faces to the images i have on the labels folder.

What I want is when someone comes in front of the camera, on the webpage to display their name - getting the information from the label.

At the moment if I do a console log its displays the names of all the images I have in my labels folder. I just want to display only the person in front of the camera i.e. Hello John to be shown under the video box.

This is my code thusfar:

JS:

```
const video = document.getElementById("video");

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri("./models"),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri("./models"),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri("./models"),
]).then(startWebcam);

function startWebcam() {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: false,
    })
    .then((stream) => {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

function getLabeledFaceDescriptions() {
  const labels = ["Bibinur", "Emunrich", "Mukthar", "NursultanAhmetsha"];
  return Promise.all(
    labels.map(async (label) => {
      const descriptions = [];
      for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        const img = await faceapi.fetchImage(`./labels/${label}/${i}.png`);
        const detections = await faceapi
          .detectSingleFace(img)
          .withFaceLandmarks()
          .withFaceDescriptor();
        descriptions.push(detections.descriptor);
        console.log(`hello ${label}`)
      }
     
      return new faceapi.LabeledFaceDescriptors(label, descriptions);
      
    })
  );
}

video.addEventListener("play", async()=>{
  const labeledFaceDescriptors = await getLabeledFaceDescriptions();
  const faceMatcher = new faceapi.FaceMatcher(labeledFaceDescriptors);

  
    const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video);
    document.body.append(canvas);

    const displaySize = {width: video.width, height: video.height};
faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize);

setInterval(async ()=>{
  const detections = await faceapi
  .detectAllFaces(video)
  .withFaceLandmarks()
  .withFaceDescriptors();

  const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
  canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  const results = resizedDetections.map((d) => {
    return faceMatcher.findBestMatch(d.descriptor);
  });
  results.forEach((result, i) => {
    const box = resizedDetections[i].detection.box;
    const drawBox = new faceapi.draw.DrawBox(box, {
      label: result,
    });
    drawBox.draw(canvas);
   
  });
}, 100);
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Face Detection on the browser</title>

    <script defer src="face-api.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" width="600" height="450" autoplay>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Manage to work it out...all i had to add these line of code this:

```
   let display= `hello ${result}`
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= `hello ${result}`
```

it fetches the current result shown on the screen by mapping each name from the const value of names - once it matches the detection the result is then outputted which i then invoke to display the name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).